# Sharepoint get changed attachment name from list on ItemUpdating Event

Tags: c#, events, sharepoint

J have sharepoint 'ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)' event.

This event need to work on 'document library' and 'generic list' with attachments. On 'document library' it works quite good, but in 'generic list' I have a litle problem, when user changed attachment in this event (delete old one, and inserts new one).

I have something like that:

```
if (properties.List.BaseType.Equals(SPBaseType.GenericList))
               {
                   for (int index = 0; index < properties.ListItem.Attachments.Count; index++)
                   {
                       //Do something

                       string relativeFileUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(properties.ListItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix, properties.ListItem.Attachments[index]);
                       relativeFileUrl = relativeFileUrl.Remove(0, properties.Web.Site.Url.Length);

                       //Do something
                   }
               }
```

In solution like this, I have relative file url that contains url to... deleted file (not new file that was inserted).

How to get a url of new attachment that was inserted in this event???

Answer (score 0):

Item adding being a synchronous event nor the list item and attachments are committed in database. Hence if you need to get the attachments in ItemAdding() event then you could do so by ASP.NET request object

Did you try [this](http://www.dhirendrayadav.com/2010/09/how-to-check-for-attachments-in.html) ?

Comment: Hi Ken. I added this question in june 2013. At this moment, I work in another company, where is no sharepoint, and... I don't have how to check this is it working. I worked with sharepoint over 2.5 years, and I don't want to waste more my time for this technology. BTW. Thanks for interest ;)